# Spring boot with Google Cloud SQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, google-app-engine, jdbc

im trying to deploy my spring boot app to Google App Engine Flex Environment and G Cloud MySQL DB.

I'm having issues connecting to the db.

Tried already some variants, but all unsuccessful.
[spring-boot-with-google-cloud-datastore-api-fails-to-run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37194125/spring-boot-with-google-cloud-datastore-api-fails-to-run)

My properties:

```
spring:
profiles: googlecloud
  jpa:
    database: MYSQL
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://google/myproject?cloudSqlInstance=XXXX&user=xxx&password=xxx
```

My pom.xml (the db dependencies only):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

With this configuration, im getting:

Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.SocketFactory

...Error creating repository beans...

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/SocketFactory

Comment: I have the same problem, Have you solved the issue?

Comment: @HAIFENGZHANG i make it work, but it was too unstable on gcloud, so we decided to move to aws :) good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can read more details about the change from 5x to 6x connector :
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/6.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html

For the NCDF exception, according to this issue :
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-mysql-socket-factory/issues/18

I think you have to change your dependencies :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-6</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```